# Problems with Ceph installation in Juju deployed OpenStack environment

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, ceph

We are running in to an issue setting up ceph to be used as backend for cinder using the charms. Our environment consists of OpenStack icehouse on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty). Most of the documents on ceph indicates we have to use cinder and ceph charms. However the 14.04 release notes mentions using cinder-ceph subordinate charms. With this approach we are unable to get the cinder to use the ceph backend. I was wondering if there are any pointers you have on how to setup cinder and ceph using charms ?

Thank you,
Nik

Answer (score 3):

Deploy cinder, cinder-ceph and ceph charms:

```
juju deploy cinder
juju deploy cinder-ceph
juju deploy ceph
```

Relate cinder with cinder-ceph and cinder-ceph with ceph:

```
juju add-relation cinder-ceph cinder
juju add-relation cinder-ceph ceph
```